# Getting 'Attempt to dereference null object' when adding Campaign Member

Tags: apex

```
    Account acct = (Account)SmartFactory.createSObject('Account');
    acct.Name = 'Newman Brodsky';
    insert acct;

    Contact contact = (Contact)SmartFactory.createSObject('Contact');
    contact.FirstName = 'New';
    contact.LastName = 'Contact';
    contact.AccountId = acct.Id;
    insert contact;

    Campaign c = (Campaign)SmartFactory.createSObject('Campaign');
    c.Name = 'MC Campaign';
    insert c;

    CampaignMember m = (CampaignMember)SmartFactory.createSObject('CampaignMember');
    m.Contact.Id = contact.Id;
    m.Campaign.Id = c.Id;
    insert m;
```

I have a basic test class here. Any idea why line
    `m.Contact.Id = contact.Id;`

is giving me this null pointer exception?

Comment: Try renaming the contact variable to something other than contact.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
m.ContactId = contact.Id;   
m.CampaignId = c.Id;
```

When you use dot notation, you're referencing an object. By default, standard lookup fields use Id for the actual Id, and without as a reference to the related object. These are null by default, hence the error.